# django queries filter select related

Tags: django, django-queryset

The person here is a person object returned from the request

```
PersonAddressBook.objects.select_related().get(person = person).client
```

The code above returns client object how can i rewrite it to return multiple clients.
a person object may be in multiple personaddressbook so filter and not get is what am trying to do but i want the client objects without using a for-loop

there is how the other models look

```
class Client:
    #stuff here

class Person:
    #stuff here

class PersonAddressBook:
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

this works but it will take longer and use more memory as it will load on my system i want use just database.

```
clients =[]
adbook = PersonAddressBook.objects.filter(person = person).select_related()
for contact in adbook:
    clients.append(contact.client)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `related_name` of PersonAddressBook in the Client model:

```
Client.objects.filter(personaddressbook__person=person)
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference) it *should* be `personaddressbook_set__person` but for some reason currently unknown to me the related name is generated a different way.)

I prefer specifying the `related_name` explicitly:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    pass

class Person(models.Model):
    pass

class PersonAddressBook(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, related_name='addressbooks')
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='addressbooks')
```

Now you can use the field `addressbooks` in the query:

```
Client.objects.filter(addressbooks__person=person)
```

Comment: I fixed the query. The `related_name` of ForeignKey used to contain a `_set` suffix. I'm slightly confused that this is not the case in this example.

Comment: The [backwards relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) should definitely be called `personaddressbook_set`. Unless I'm missing something important this looks a lot like a Django bug.

Comment: ok ill try this now but dose it affect my db if i but related name ?

Comment: The `related_name` is just the name of the backwards relationship in the referenced model. It does not affect the database schema.

Comment: i did this to sort by self from terminal works after the 2nd try is there a better way to sort by its str or rep cos some clinets are company some are people so there self will be set choice to sort with Client.objects.filter(addressbooks__person=person).order_by('?')

Comment: this finally did the trick Client.objects.filter(addressbooks__person = person).order_by('first_name','company_name')